# Search file from recursively broader directories

Tags: python, python-os, file-search

I would like to search for a file starting from a directory, let's say "C:/users/test1/test2/", if the file it's not found there then i would like to make the directory broader ("C:/users/test1/" for example) and so on.
Of course, since I already searched in "C:/users/test1/test2/" I need to exclude it from the search.

os.walk() looks like a good function to perform a search, but, as I mentioned, I would like to be able to step-back in the file tree and exclude already searched directories. How could I do this or, better, is there a function already implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) does accept optional argument `topdown`, if it is `True` then

> the caller can modify the dirnames list in-place (perhaps using del or
> slice assignment), and walk() will only recurse into the
> subdirectories whose names remain in dirnames; this can be used to
> prune the search, impose a specific order of visiting, or even to
> inform walk() about directories the caller creates or renames before
> it resumes walk() again. Modifying dirnames when topdown is False has
> no effect on the behavior of the walk, because in bottom-up mode the
> directories in dirnames are generated before dirpath itself is
> generated.

So you should be able to exclude unwanted (already visited catalog) by using this feature.

Comment: Thanks, @Daweo, this is useful to know. The only problem is that with walk I cannot start the search from the directory where my file is probable to be saved. I.e. I want to start the search from "C:/users/test1/test2/" because the file is probably saved there, but if it turns out not to be there I'll receive an empty 3-tuple from os.walk(). Instead of this behavior, I would like to step back to "C:/users/test1/" and exclude the previously searched directories. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @mbrivio `os.walk` will never give totally empty tuple, as at least 1st element (`dirpath`) will not be empty

Comment: This is better than just starting the search from "C:/users/test1/" because there might be other folders In "C:/users/test1/" in which is improbable to find the file and in which I don't want to search unnecessarily.

Comment: yes ok, but I don't need it to return me the dirpath if the file is not there.

Comment: @mbrivio note that you might alter dirnames in place to *impose a specific order of visiting*